# What is Vanilla?

Tags: terminology

What do people mean with the term "*Vanilla*"?

I see it more and more often. For example, with regard to [World of Warcraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/9926/69152):

> Which Vanilla achievements will be lost with Cataclysm’s release?

And also in [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/186376/69152) about Minecraft.

> If you're playing Vanilla...

Comment: It's worth pointing out that there's a [Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanilla_software) on Vanilla software.

Comment: It's used almost in every game. Starcraft, Quake (referring to the original physics as VQ3 or Vainilla Quake 3), among other games with gameplay-enhancing mods.

Comment: I could have sworn I've seen this question here before...

Comment: Found it. Same question on English Stack Exchange: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/182519/what-does-vanilla-mean-in-the-context-of-gaming I knew I've seen it before :)

Comment: [No whips or chains can be used](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanilla_sex)

Comment: @DVK as mentioned as an [example question](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/62814/sex-and-intimacy/75058#75058) in a proposed Stack Exchange!

Comment: Vanilla can also be used to describe a character or default load-out in a game. e.g. I can not wait to get out of my vanilla armour and don my robe and wizard hat of doom +4.

Comment: Remember that Vanilla is not the trendiest flavor, but is far and away the most popular. #foodforthought

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Vanilla usually means [the base game, without any modifications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanilla_software) or in WoW's case DLC's/Expansion packs.

Comment: Another term for this (often used by KSP) is "stock", or what ships with the game.

Comment: Or, also used quite a bit in the WoW community, "classic".

Answer (score 38):

> Computer software [...] is called Vanilla when not customized from its original form, meaning that it is used without any customizations or updates applied to it.
>   - [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanilla_software)

Hence, not especially in WoW, it means only the base software without any expansions/add-ons.

As for the origin of the term..I don't really want to get into that, just look up "SMBC vanilla", right?

Comment: In fact, the article specifically mentions World of Warcraft: "For example, World of Warcraft could refer to either the original game or one of the four expansion packs, so users may refer to the original as "vanilla" to distinguish it from the subsequent versions."

Comment: Yes. For example, due to it being a rather popular game. Vanilla is a term also used outside of software, anyway, as has been stated.

Comment: It is strange that "vanilla" means plain, when in fact vanilla is a flavouring, just as is strawberry or toffee. Why don't people just use "plain"? I don't know!

Comment: @PaddyLandau  You'd probably get a more thorough explanation at the ELU site, but it seems that many ice creams are essentially vanilla plus added flavoring, e.g. vanilla with cherries in it.  The base vanilla is thus the plain alternative to a more complicated mix.

Comment: @Brythan thank you. I hadn't realised that non-vanilla ice creams contained vanilla.

Comment: Vanilla is considered the "default" flavor of ice cream, at least in the US.

Comment: Please note that the explanation of SMBC is wrong: http://www.linguistrix.com/blog/?p=738

Comment: Has been noted in the answer below.

Comment: Note: for games with expansions (dlc) "vanilla" is usually anything before the first expansion. So in the case of WoW any 1.x patch is vanilla, even though the game has had updates before. For games that get lots of patches with minor changes, people usually stop calling it vanilla after the first major game-changing patch.

Answer (score 23):

When applied to technology, the word *vanilla* means  “ordinary, default, unmodified”. When specifically applied to gaming, it means the default game, without any add-ons.

[Shaeldon speculated](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/186387) that this meaning might derive from vanilla ice-cream being the first and still the most frequent flavour. [No. 7892142 hinted](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/186386) at a sexual meaning. They’re both right: the [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=vanilla) has this to say about *vanilla*:

> 1660s, “pod of the vanilla plant,” from Spanish *vainilla* “vanilla plant,” literally “little pod,” diminutive of *vaina* “sheath,” from Latin *vagina* “sheath of an ear of grain, hull of a plant” (see *[vagina](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=vagina)*). So called from the shape of the pods. European discovery 1521 by Hernando Cortes’ soldiers on reconnaissance in southeastern Mexico. Meaning “flavoring extracted from the vanilla bean” is attested by 1728. Meaning “conventional, of ordinary sexual preferences” is 1970s, from notion of whiteness and the common choice of vanilla ice cream.

Etymological dictionaries tend to work in reverse chronological order, as they describe where words *come* from. So let’s recast this. A Latin word for a sheath, scabbard, or the hull of a plant was inherited into Spanish, where a diminutive (“little pod”) was applied to a certain plant. That plant name came into English where the meaning was expanded to include the flavouring extracted from the beans of the plant.

As this flavouring was the default in ice-cream, it was expanded metaphorically to refer to “conventional” or “ordinary” sexual preferences (i.e., non-BDSM) and from there to various other meanings of conventional, default, or ordinary.  It is now particularly prevalent in technological circles.*

---

Incidentally, yes, the word *vanilla* is etymologically related to *vagina* but this is, in fact, [completely unrelated](http://www.linguistrix.com/blog/?p=738) to this usage. They developed independently.

---

* This, at least, is my experience. In fact, this use of *vanilla* is found in all sorts of contexts, but *in my personal experience* the two most prevalent contexts are the original (sex) and technology.

---

<sub>I spend far more of my time on [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/) than I do on Arqade.</sub>

Comment: Holy in-depth etymology batman! This is a wonderfully, over-the-top explanation, thank you.

Comment: Thanks, @AWinkle. I'm far more interested in language than I am in gaming, so this one was right in my bailiwick. And this is quite an interesting etymology, given the wonderful coincidence that two distinct sexual meanings evolved completely independently from the same root non-sexual word.

Answer (score 5):

> Vanilla:
>
> adjective - informal adjective: vanilla; adjective: plain vanilla
>
> 1. having no special or extra features; ordinary or standard.
>      "choosing plain vanilla technology wherever you can will save you money"

(definition compliments of google).

When applied to games/software, it refers to the game without modifications (custom mods or expansions). It can also mean that no updates were applied to the base game.